# SqlAlchemy query db.session.query() output format into HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a db query with sqlalchemy and then pushing this output into an HTML page with flask and python.  However, the output is formatted as a list, and I am trying to remove the quotes around it and format it nicer.

```
# views.py
@buyers_blueprint.route('/welcome')
@login_required
def welcome_user():
    user = current_user
    events = db.session.query(Events.eventname)
    return render_template('welcome.html', user=user, events=events)
```

The welcome.html page is simple and looks like this

```
welcome.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Events Dashboard</h1>
    <p>{{user}}! You are logged in.<br>
        Here is a list of your events</p><br>
    <p>
        {% for event in events %}
        <li>{{event}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The output looks like this.

```
('Event 1',)
('Event 2',)
```

How do I remove the quotes, and comma to format it so it looks nicer?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to help from others, I came up with an answer.  In the HTML, I just needed to ask for the first in tuple.

```
welcome.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Events Dashboard</h1>
    <p>{{user}}! You are logged in.<br>
        Here is a list of your events</p><br>
    <p>
        {% for event in events %}
        <li>{{event[0]}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```